# create select field using api with name/value pairs

Tags: channel-fields, drop-down, api

Anyone have any example or documentation to create a select field using the EE api in a channel group with name/value pairs for the select option.  I cannot find anything on how to do that. I am able to create the select field itself, just not with name/value pairs for the options.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out, here is what I ended up with.

```
    ee()->load->library('api');
    ee()->legacy_api->instantiate('channel_fields');

    $field = ee('Model')->make('ChannelField');
    $field->group_id = $group_id;
    $field->site_id = $site_id;
    $field->field_name = $field_name;
    $field->field_type = 'select';
    $field->set(array(
        'field_label' => $field_label,
        'field_order' => $field_order,
        'field_required' => 'n',
        'field_search' => 'y',
        'field_is_hidden' => 'n',
        'field_instructions' => '',
        'field_maxl' => null,
        'field_show_fmt' => 'y',
        'field_fmt' => 'br',
        'text_field_show_fmt' => 'y',
        'text_field_text_direction' => 'ltr',
        'text_field_content_type' => 'any',
        'text_field_show_smileys' => 'n',
        'text_field_show_glossary' => 'n',
        'text_field_show_spellcheck' => 'n',
        'text_field_show_file_selector' => 'n',
        'field_pre_populate' => 'v',  
        'value_label_pairs' => array(
            'default' => 'Default',
            'option_2' => 'Option 2',
            'option_3' => 'Option 3'
        ),
    ));

    $field->save();
```